# How to verify the access_token of Sign in with Apple?

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

I saw the description

> You may verify the refresh token up to once a day to confirm that the user’s Apple ID on that device is still in good standing with Apple’s servers.

in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/verifying_a_user .

I have two question about the description:

1. Why should we verify the `refresh token` instead of  `access token` to confirm the user's Apple ID is still in good standing with Apple's server?
2. The doc said refresh token can only verify **once a day**. But i can verify refresh token **multiple times** in practice. Is there some conflict between documentation and implementation?

[image]

Update on 10/17/2019：

> For apps running on other systems, use the periodic successful verification of the refresh token to determine the lifetime of the user session.

I also saw the description above in in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/verifying_a_user . I think `periodic` is also conflict with `once a day`.

Right now, I store the access_token and set custom expires time for follow verify request. And get notification from iOS client(getCridentialState) to delete access_token.

Comment: Apple says they *may* throttle your server if you attempt to validate the refresh token more than once per day.

Comment: I think you mean "identity token" and not access token in your question. This is relevant because at least on the server-side, Apple talks about both an identity token and an access token, with the access token not yet used. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/tokenresponse

Comment: In terms of "Why should we verify the refresh token instead of  [identity] token to confirm the user's Apple ID is still in good standing with Apple's server?". The identity token is short lived. Its expiry time is a few minutes. The refresh token (AFAIK) doesn't expire-- at least until the user revokes the apps credentials.